# Nim vs Rock - how they are different?

Tags: compare, nim-lang

I knew about [Nim](http://nim-lang.org/) and then learned about [Rock](https://ooc-lang.org/). They seem fairly similar, both transcompile to C.

What are the main differences between them? Which one would you recommend?

Comment: Last time I checked Rock out, it seems to be geared more towards scripting compared to Nim. In addition, Rock appears to be less actively developed these days (judging from their mailing-list/forum contents, at least).

Comment: Simply compiling to C does not make them similar. C is just the backend, like LLVM is to Rust or clang.

Comment: Also, this isn't the kind of question for StackOverflow. I recommend the [Software Recommendation Stack Exchange](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 5):

There's not much documentation on [ooc](http://ooc-lang.org) of which rock is the compiler. Here are the key differences I've found. Disclaimer: i'm a bit biased towards Nim ;).

- Metaprogramming. While Nim offers powerful tools to please even the most extreme metaprogrammers, ooc has nothing to do with it.
- Domain Specific Language (DSL) friendliness. Nim is better extendable with custom DSLs thanx to its syntax, metaprogramming capabilities and operator overload support.
- Nim compiles (and provides decent FFI) to C/C++/Objective-C and JavaScript, while rock compiles to C only.
- Nim is actively developed and supported. As of this writing last commit to rock was made half a year ago.
- Syntax. That's an obvious one. Nim is somewhere in python+pascal camp. OOC is more of a coffeescript but with curly braces.

There may be more key differences depending on what is important to you, but my overall opinion is that Nim is a much more sophisticated and feature-rich language, with which you're less likely to hit any limitations when writing anything bigger than a couple-of-files project.